# DataTable doesn't effect on the table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

I am using DataTable library in MVC, but it doesn't work
this is the view Part

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

 <script type="text/javascript">

//$(document).ready(function () {
//    $('#example').DataTable();
//})

$(document).ready(function () {
        GetEmployeeRecord();
})  

var GetEmployeeRecord = function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "/BasicInfo/GetCustomers",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("success");
            BindDataTable(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    })

}

var BindDataTable = function (response) {

    $("#example").DataTable({

        "aaData": response,
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "Id" },
            { "mData": "Phone" },
            { "mData": "FirstName" },
            { "mData": "lastName" }              
        ]
    });
}
```

and this is Controller Part

```
 public JsonResult GetCustomers()
    {
        SalonEntities db = new SalonEntities();
        List<Customer> CustomerList = db.Customers.OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).ToList();               
        return Json(CustomerList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

although the  CustomerList in controller is loaded but it returns to the view it enters the error section of jquery
what could be the problram

Comment: why "aaData" and "aoColumns"? The docs say it should be ["data"](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) and ["columns"](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax call to your controller failed. To debug this, you can do two things:

### Alert the error

Remove the (dobule quote) `"` to alert the actual error.

```
    error: function () {
        alert(error);
    }
```

You will most probably be able to see it in developer tools in your console.

### Check the network tab

In your network tab, you'll see the error (4XX, 5XX) or something like that with some extra information (if you are lucky).

If no more information is there and you have an error 500, you need to check the exception in your backend code.

Comment: it has error 500, but the backend code returns the list perfectly

Comment: Check your event viewer on the server side to see what's the error.